# preg_match_all count match word using $row

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to find the number of words in a string using `$row` but I don't know how.

Inside this variable `$row['item_name']`:

`IphoneAsus Strix LaptopIphoneBagIphoneCalculatorMakeupIphoneWalletIphone`

I'm using this code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 

        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","matching");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM item";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("Invalid Query: $sql");

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo "<tr>
                <td align='center'>" . $row["id"] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['sub1_type'] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['sub2_brand'] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['sub3_model'] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['sub4_color'] . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                </tr>";

                //inside this $row['item_name']: Iphone, Asus Strix Laptop, Iphone, Bag, Iphone, Calculator, Makeup, Iphone, Wallet, Iphone

                echo $number = preg_match_all('/Iphone/', $row['item_name']);
                // output:1010100101
            }
        }

        ?>
</table><br><br>
    <?php
    $a="IphoneAsus Strix LaptopIphoneBagIphoneCalculatorMakeupIphoneWalletIphone";    
    echo $number = preg_match_all('/Iphone/', $a); //ouput:5  
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output should be: `5`

But the output show: `1010100101`

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: [I get `5`](https://ideone.com/GYBV6q).

Comment: [me too](https://3v4l.org/7UfjV)

Comment: Try `$number = preg_match_all('/Iphone/', $row['item_name']);` and then `echo $number;` but I suppose there is something in your code you do not share with us.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I fixed it

Comment: How many rows are in your database table? Is the output `1010100101` for each row or is it displaying as such after all the rows have been output?

Comment: @JustinPearce - 10 rows. I don't know why the output: `1010100101` but each row detect the word Iphone which is `1` but `0` not match the word.

Comment: In your edit, do the commas indicate the value for that field for each row?

Comment: In the first row you have `Iphone` but not in the second row etc.

Comment: @Toto - i know, what i mean is each row will detect if there is `Iphone`. if `Iphone` detect or match then how many numbers `Iphone` are there.

Comment: @JustinPearce - I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. but i want to know how many will detect `Iphone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, `$row['item_name']` doesn't contain `IphoneAsus Strix LaptopIphoneBagIphoneCalculatorMakeupIphoneWalletIphone` but each row contain:

1. `Iphone` --> 1 match
2. `Asus Strix Laptop` --> 0 match
3. `Iphone`  --> 1 match
4. `Bag`  --> 0 match
5. `Iphone` --> 1 match

...

So for your 10 rows you have `1010100101`

Have a look at the source of the generated page, you do not have `1010100101` but `1` then `0` then `1` then `0`... between the `<tr>...</tr>`

I suggest you to change the line:

```
echo $number = preg_match_all('/Iphone/', $row['item_name']);
```

with:

```
$number += preg_match_all('/Iphone/', $row['item_name']);
```

then after the while loop:

```
echo $number;
```

Here you will have `5` as expected.

Comment: @DarrenDignaran: Remove the `echo $number...`, replace it with `$number += preg_match_all..` and put `echo $number` AFTER the while loop. No more `echo` within the while loop

Comment: Thanks, i did not put `echo $number` after the while loop before.